# Symfony2 http_cache in custom location

Tags: php, symfony, caching

In Symfony2, the command for clearing cache ...

```
  php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

removes completely the app/cache/prod  folder. I'd like to preserve the content of http_cache. Is there any way to tell Symfony2 to store the http_cache in other location not affected when do a cache:clear?

For example, there is a simple configuration in config.yml to move sessions out of cache folder, in order to not clear all user sessions on every deployment.

```
framework:
[...]
session:
    save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions
```

Is there some similar way to do this with http_cache folder?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

Comment: this is not the case @zalex, this documentation shows how to override the whole cache directory, but I want only to override http_cache subdirectory. Pawel response is right.

Comment: my mistake, sorry, didn't understand question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppCache.php` you can use `createStore` method.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;

class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    protected function createStore()
    {
        // Use custom logic to build the store
    }
}
```

[Default content](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/HttpCache/HttpCache.php#L78) of that function looks like that:

```
protected function createStore()
{
    return new Store($this->cacheDir ?: $this->kernel->getCacheDir().'/http_cache');
}
```

Comment: Great, this did the trick!!

`return new Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\Store ($this->rootDir ?: $this->kernel->getRootDir().'/var/http_cache');`